# autocomplete textbox in windows application with not only prefix search

Tags: c#, winforms

Autocomplete textbox searches only prefix text but I want search string in the following manner:

if my search string is abc then result will be

abcz,
   aabc,
   rabc

Comment: @MongZhu No his question is a little different.

Comment: Please explain what is different.

Comment: thanks steve.
my question is different

Comment: autocomplete textbox gives only prefix result,

Comment: @Steve I've suggested an edit to the question, have a look at that.

Comment: @ShardulWagh Ok, then I probably misunderstood the question

Comment: @MongZhu  I had suggested an edit, I don't know where it disappeared, anyway I'm working on the answer now. Thanks.